# How to identify or remember user's browser in Django

Tags: django, browser, authentication, alert

I am trying to implement an alert when a user logs in from a new browser. Is there any method to identify a browser like UDID for mobile devices? 
`request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')` will provide the browser type. But I am looking to distinguish between browser a user logs in. Whether it be from same computer or different one.

Comment: That is called a _new session_.

Comment: But a session expires when the browser is closed.  and when the user opens the browser again,  a new session is created.  So how can that be used to remember a browser?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: @Kritz Nope. What I did is generate a UID whenever a user logs in and the clients store it in their local storage. This is passed in every request in the header. Wrote a middleware to validate it. I am sure, it is not a clean method. But it works.